# How to write specific row when condition is met in another Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am in a learning stage of Java. I want to write a program in Java which reads one Excel file (.xlsx). This file has some columns and many rows. I want to write the data in another Excel file (.xlsx) only the condition is met not all the data from existing file.

My Excel sheet looks like below

[image]

I want to filter only those rows with broker Edelweiss and put it in another Excel sheet. I am aware how to copy all the data from one Excel to another Excel using Java. I don't know how to filter a specific row and put it in another Excel.

Here is my code.

```java
     FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("broker.xlsx"));
    //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
 
    //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 
    //Iterate through each rows one by one
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
    {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        //For each row, iterate through all the columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
         
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            //Check the cell type and format accordingly
            switch (cell.getCellType()) 
            {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    file.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting the below error when I run Axel Richter's code which is shared below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic.valueOf(FileMagic.java:209)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:222)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185)
    at writefile.main(writefile.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

I have included below jars in my classpath

```
POI_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/poi-5.2.2.jar
POI_OOXML_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2.jar
XML_BEANS_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar
COM_COLL_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/lib/commons-collections4-4.4.jar

COM_COMPRESS_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/ooxml-lib/commons-compress-1.21.jar
COM_CODEC_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/lib/commons-codec-1.15.jar
COM_IO_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/lib/commons-io-2.11.0.jar
COM_MATH_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/lib/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
LOG_J4_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/lib/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar
SPARSE_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar
COM_LOGG_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/ooxml-lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
CURVE_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/ooxml-lib/curvesapi-1.07.jar
SLF4_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/ooxml-lib/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? I would open the source sheet and loop through all rows in it. For each row I would get the content of the column where "Broker" is stored. Then, if that content equals "Edelweiss" I would get that row into a Java collection, a list of rows for example. After that I would write the content of that Java collection into the result sheet.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you for quick reply. Presently i have programmed only to read the excel sheet and printing it out. i have no idea how to put the filtered content in another excel sheet. i will share the code

Comment: @AxelRichter Can you please give me a sample code

Comment: You told in your question: "I am aware how to copy all the data from one excel to another excel using java." That seems not true. At least your code does not do something like that.

Comment: @AxelRichter i have written one more program which reads entire excel sheet and writes in another sheet. its a copy. i am not aware how to write only specific columns when my criteria is met . Anyways you have given me some suggestion how to do it. i will try to find it. Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: If you encounter a specific problem, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that reproduces the problem you describe.

Comment: @AxelRichter. Thank you for solving my problem. Highly appreciate it.

Comment: @AxelRichter i am getting some error which i pasted in my question above. Can you please tell which all jars you have included in your classpath

Comment: There seems to be an old version of `commons-io` somewhere in your class-path. The `commons-io-2.11.0.jar` contains the class `org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream`. But if an old version of `commons-io` is somewhere in your class-path then the class loader might use this old version and thus does not find that class.

Comment: @AxelRichter. Issue got fixed. after including the below jar

POI_EXAM_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/poi-examples-5.2.2.jar
POI_EXCEL_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/poi-excelant-5.2.2.jar
POI_JAVA_DOC_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/poi-javadoc-5.2.2.jar
POI_SCRATCH_LIB=$(TOP_DIR)/jar/poi-bin-5.2.2/poi-scratchpad-5.2.2.jar

Comment: Those jars have nothing to do with that problem. But maybe your IDE made some class-path-cleaning process after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make my comment an answer.

I would open the source sheet and loop through all rows in it. For each row I would get the content of the column where "Broker" is stored. Then, if that content equals "Edelweiss" I would get that row into a Java collection, a list of rows for example. After that I would write the content of that Java collection into the result sheet.

The following complete example shows this.

It contains methods to get the last filled row in a special column of a sheet and to get the last filled column in a special row of a sheet. That is to determine the used cell range of a sheet.

It also contains a method to get the headings, which maps headings to column indexes. The headings must be in first row of the used cell range of the sheet.

It also shows how to use [CellUtil.copyCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html#copyCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellCopyPolicy-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellCopyContext-) to copy cells from one sheet to another.

The code is tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.2`.

The first sheet of `broker.xlsx` looks like:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class ExcelFilterRowsToNewWorkbook {
    
 static int getLastFilledRow(Sheet sheet, int col) {
  int lastStoredRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
  for (int r = lastStoredRowNum; r >= 0; r--) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
   if (row != null) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(col);
    if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() != CellType.BLANK) return row.getRowNum();  
   }       
  }
  return -1; // the sheet is empty in that col 
 }
 
 static int getLastFilledColumn(Sheet sheet, int rowIdx) {
  int lastStoredCellNum = sheet.getRow(rowIdx).getLastCellNum();
  Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIdx);
  if (row != null) {
   for (int c = lastStoredCellNum; c >= 0; c--) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
    if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() != CellType.BLANK) return cell.getColumnIndex();  
   }       
  }
  return -1; // the sheet is empty in that row 
 }
 
 static Map<Integer, String> getHeadings(Sheet sheet) {
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(new Locale("en", "US"));
  dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
  int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
  int firstCol = sheet.getRow(firstRow).getFirstCellNum();
  int lastCol = getLastFilledColumn(sheet, firstRow);   
  Map<Integer, String> headings = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
  Row row = sheet.getRow(firstRow);
  if (row != null) {
   for (int c = firstCol; c <= lastCol; c++) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
    headings.put(c, dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));      
   }
  }
  return headings;
 }

 static List<Row> filterRows(Sheet sheet, String filterHeading, String filterValue) {
  int filterCol = -1;
  Map<Integer, String> headings = getHeadings(sheet);
  for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : headings.entrySet()) {
   if (entry.getValue().equals(filterHeading)) {
    filterCol = entry.getKey();
    break;
   }       
  }
  List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
  // add the headings row
  int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
  rows.add(sheet.getRow(firstRow));
  // add the fildered rows
  if (filterCol > -1) {
   DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(new Locale("en", "US"));
   dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
   int firstCol = sheet.getRow(firstRow).getFirstCellNum();
   int lastCol = getLastFilledColumn(sheet, firstRow);   
   int lastRow = getLastFilledRow(sheet, firstCol);
   for (int r = firstRow; r <= lastRow; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
    if (row != null && lastCol >= filterCol) {
     Cell cell = row.getCell(filterCol);
     String cellContent = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
     if (cellContent.equals(filterValue)) {
      rows.add(row);   
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return rows;  
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  try (Workbook workbookSrc = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./broker.xlsx")) ) {

   Sheet sheetSrc = workbookSrc.getSheetAt(0);
   // get filtered rows
   List<Row> rowsSrc = filterRows(sheetSrc, "Broker", "Edelweiss");
   
   // add filtered rows in new workbook
   try (Workbook workbookDest = WorkbookFactory.create(true);
        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./brokerFiltered.xlsx") ) {
    Sheet sheetDest = workbookDest.createSheet();
    int r = 0;
    for (Row rowSrc : rowsSrc) {
     Row rowDest = sheetDest.createRow(r++);
     for (Cell cellSrc : rowSrc) {
      Cell cellDest = rowDest.createCell(cellSrc.getColumnIndex());
      CellUtil.copyCell(cellSrc, 
       cellDest, 
       new CellCopyPolicy(),
       new CellCopyContext()
      );
     }         
    }  
    workbookDest.write(fileout);
   }
   
  }   
  
 }
}
```

The first sheet of `brokerFiltered.xlsx` then looks like:

[image]